# Font smoothing/anti-aliasing when using Quartz2d on iOS?

Tags: ios, uikit, quartz-graphics

I have a custom UIView that generates some kind of diagram that needs a height notated with a number.

All drawing goes ok, it antialiases correctly when creating circles etc. with quartz2d. 

However, when I want to draw a NSString to the context, the font-smoothing/anti-aliasing is messed up. 
Disabling anti-aliasing does result in a thinner text, so the switch does work, however, the anti-aliased text is awfull. It doesn't look as crisp at all as the normal text rendered in iOS.

```
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES); 
CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(context, YES);
NSString *stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", input.height];
UIFont *font = [UIFont  systemFontOfSize:textsize]; 

[stringValue drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y) withFont:font];
```

I am out of clues on how to solve this font rendering issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to just add several `UILabel` programmatically with the right coordinates. These `UILabel` instances rendered the text perfectly, so this solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to forego the anti-aliasing on the text you could save the context with anti-aliasing turned on.

```
GCContextSaveGState(context);
```

Turn anti-aliasing off and render the text:

```
GCContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
NSString *stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", input.height];
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:textSize];

[stringValue drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y) withFont:font];
```

Then restore the graphics context back to it's previous space. (with anti-aliasing turned on) to render the remaining parts of the drawing.

```
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```